# In xcode 9: Why status bar set white when hide navigation bar?

Tags: ios11, xcode9, uistatusbar

Since Xcode update to 9 the status bar stay with white background if I hide the navigation bar:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Before, it kept the color of the navigation bar.

The only solution was to create a new status bar:

```
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
let statusBarColor = Constants.Colors.Blue
statusBarView.backgroundColor = statusBarColor
view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Why it works like this now? It is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same issue.

You have to disable "Adjust Scroll View Insets" for your ViewController in the Storyboard/XIB, that's all !